# Scrapy error on redirects to PDF file: AttributeError: Response content isn't text

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I've got a scrapy spider hosted on Zyte using Smart Proxies.

My spider is fairly simple as it crawls starts from a list of URLs.

the parse method uses a simple linkextractor to extract links on the domain and then crawls those links.

Simplified parse method:

```
def parse(self, response):    
    internal_le = LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains=tld_t, # try to stay on domain (this is a tldextract of response.url)
            unique=True,  # de-dup
            #deny_extensions=self.deny_extensions
        )
    in_links = internal_le.extract_links(response)

    for link in in_links:
            if link.url:
                
                yield Request(
                    link.url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    
                )
```

Because deny_extensions defaults to scrapy.DENY_EXTENSIONS which includes PDF files, I assumed it would not crawl a PDF link.  But, I have internal links that are redirected to externally hosted PDF files.

Here are some extracts from logs with examples:

```
33: 2023-11-27 23:41:01 ERROR   [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1691073836/usd262net/renyendq5njmpmol8iko/2023-2024USD262ElementarySchoolStudentHandbookFinaldocx.pdf> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about) More 
34: 2023-11-27 23:41:02 ERROR   [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://resources.finalsite.net/files/v1676910235/usd262net/kgtnfuk7buzu8zthtixk/102422RevisedSpanish22-23ElementaryHandbookSP4.docx> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about) More
35: 2023-11-27 23:41:05 ERROR   [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1676649887/usd262net/adlo2wuxxpqa7pmnxmkx/MiddleSchoolBellSchedule22_23docx.pdf> (referer: https://vcms.usd262.net/about) More 
36: 2023-11-27 23:41:10 ERROR   [scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <GET https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1691073617/usd262net/zjuysts6fymaf5gjumlc/VCMSStudentHandbook23-24Finaldocx.pdf> (referer: https://vcms.usd262.net/about) More
```

And here is a single trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 279, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 350, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh_scrapy/middlewares.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 352, in <genexpr>
    return (self._set_referer(r, response) for r in result or ())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 31, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if self._filter(r, response, spider))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 106, in process_sync
    for r in iterable:
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg/edtech/spiders/edcrawler.py", line 117, in parse
    ex_links = external_le.extract_links(response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py", line 239, in extract_links
    base_url = get_base_url(response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/response.py", line 26, in get_base_url
    text = response.text[0:4096]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 137, in text
    raise AttributeError("Response content isn't text")
AttributeError: Response content isn't text
```

I've tried various approaches to change my link extractor but presumably the link looks fine to the link extractor.  Its the redirect that has the PDF file which gets downloaded and produces the error.

Example start url [start url](https://west.usd262.net/about)

link on that page extracted into 'in_links'  [extracted internal link](https://west.usd262.net/fs/resource-manager/view/2e1fe1a1-4c3e-475f-9ddd-b05eb7ed3320)

redirect  [redirect to a pdf document on web host](https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1691073836/usd262net/renyendq5njmpmol8iko/2023-2024USD262ElementarySchoolStudentHandbookFinaldocx.pdf)

The only thing I can think of to fix this issue is a custom middleware piece that replaces the redirect and looks for r".pdf$" in the request.url.

[https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect](https://west.usd262.net/about)

Am I missing something?  using latest scrapy 2.11.0.
also, logged issue on scrapy github [github/6159](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/6159).

[1](https://west.usd262.net/about): scrapy docs.redirect middleware

Comment: Afterthought.  Wondering if simple request.meta[dont_redirect] = True would avoid complex custom middleware. What else would I miss that typical content management systems redirect to for files?  Other media?  Ok with that.  But not a redirect to a legit link.

Comment: @Alexander loading multiple pdf(or any other) files - most likely will cause overusage of RAM and scrapy doesn't have built-in possibility to prevent it. If something similar previously happened - it is preferred to.. prevent downloading of pdf at all costs

Comment: I agree.  Expensive for a broad crawl.  I’m thinking I need to avoid them.  But if I ‘dont_rediirect’ on all links, I’m wondering what else I miss on my crawl.   I’m crawling public school districts.

Comment: 'dont_redirect' helps the error rate a lot but it doesn't fix all of them.   Cases where a link has no "PDF" in the extension but the CMS serves up a PDF in the response.   No redirect occurs with this.  Only way to do this is probably to intercept with a header response as header does show a PDF is coming.  Requires signal intercept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option in this situation would be to subclass the `RedirectMiddleware` and simply add in a few lines that check the Location header of the initial response for the `.pdf`  extension and raise the `IgnoreRequest` Exception if it is found.

This can all be done in just a handful of lines.

Example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect import RedirectMiddleware
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class PDFRedirect(RedirectMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        location = response.headers.get("Location", b"").decode()
        if location.lower().endswith(".pdf") or location.lower().endswith(".docx"):
            print(f"IGNORING PDF {location}")
            raise IgnoreRequest("max redirections reached")
        return super().process_response(request, response, spider)


class PdfRedirectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nopdfs'
    allowed_domains = ['west.usd262.net']
    start_urls = ['https://west.usd262.net/about']

    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES" : {
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware":None,
            PDFRedirect: 600,
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        internal_le = LinkExtractor(unique=True)
        in_links = internal_le.extract_links(response)
        for link in in_links:
                if link.url:
                    yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

OUTPUT

```
2023-11-30 15:00:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-11-30 15:00:35 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-11-30 15:00:35 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-11-30 15:00:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about> (referer: None)
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://west.usd262.net/about> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.usd262.net': <GET https://www.usd262.net/staff-links1>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'abilene.usd262.net': <GET https://abilene.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'wheatland.usd262.net': <GET https://wheatland.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'vcis.usd262.net': <GET https://vcis.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'vcms.usd262.net': <GET https://vcms.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'vchs.usd262.net': <GET https://vchs.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'tlc.usd262.net': <GET https://tlc.usd262.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.facebook.com': <GET https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100061273524317>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'twitter.com': <GET https://twitter.com/USD262>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.youtube.com': <GET https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCD8AdyKpM44gpFzqIqBG9tw>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262net-22-us-central1-01.preview.finalsitecdn.com': <GET https://usd262net-22-us-central1-01.preview.finalsitecdn.com/about/calendar1>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.finalsite.com': <GET https://www.finalsite.com>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about#fsPageContent> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/files/v1676910235/usd262net/kgtnfuk7buzu8zthtixk/102422RevisedSpanish22-23ElementaryHandbookSP4.docx
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/privacy-policy> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1686234716/usd262net/hdkhsv6qg1jzbobmkrxs/23-24elementaryschoolsupplylist8511in.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/contact645-clone> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/3813>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/accessibility-statement> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.valleycenterhornets.net': <GET https://www.valleycenterhornets.net>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'sideline.bsnsports.com': <GET https://sideline.bsnsports.com/schools/kansas/valleycenter/valley-center-high-school/design/picker>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262net-34-us-central1-01.preview.finalsitecdn.com': <GET https://usd262net-34-us-central1-01.preview.finalsitecdn.com/about>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'calendar.google.com': <GET https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=usd262.net_b07qmrijq7dq09a7s93u4qq7u0%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FChicago>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'datacentral.ksde.org': <GET https://datacentral.ksde.org/accountability.aspx>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1691073836/usd262net/renyendq5njmpmol8iko/2023-2024USD262ElementarySchoolStudentHandbookFinaldocx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.w3.org': <GET http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/>
2023-11-30 15:00:37 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'accessibilitystatementgenerator.com': <GET http://accessibilitystatementgenerator.com>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/parent756> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/pto> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/site-map> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/footer-links> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262.infinitecampus.org': <GET https://usd262.infinitecampus.org/campus/portal/valleycenter.jsp>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262net.finalsite.com': <GET https://usd262net.finalsite.com/fs/resource-manager/view/383a8f18-5ef9-4f48-815e-030300759293>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'docs.google.com': <GET https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/e/2PACX-1vRi840waukqIIVzL9eM4X9EoxwIsGKyuwsu83A852Mv6dMnPmjQSF0HKFRrMmpw1g/pubhtml>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262.incidentiq.com': <GET https://usd262.incidentiq.com/>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'educatekansas.org': <GET https://educatekansas.org/>
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/volunteering> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/ymca-childcare> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'ymcawichita.org': <GET https://ymcawichita.org/programs/child-care-and-camps/before-and-after-school>
2023-11-30 15:00:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/emergency-safety-interventions-bullying> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/librarymedia-center> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/volunteer-information> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'search.follettsoftware.com': <GET https://search.follettsoftware.com/metasearch/ui/43691>
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'bookfairs.scholastic.com': <GET https://bookfairs.scholastic.com/bf/westelementaryschool11>
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.commonsensemedia.org': <GET https://www.commonsensemedia.org/>
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/news> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/3814>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1680193574/usd262net/skenieqeiwealjrpl210/33023ActivationInstructionforCampusPortal3.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673804004/usd262net/i0mi93dw4rp63jsem0jt/PTOMeetingMinutes1220docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/contact645-clone> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/sraff-directory> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.usd262.net/schools> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/2799>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803989/usd262net/bvokssior5jikny5ggwk/PTOMeetingMinutes2120docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/report-bullying-safety-concerns> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/3560>
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/counseling> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.ksde.org': <GET http://www.ksde.org/Default.aspx?tabid=149>
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.homeworkkansas.org': <GET http://www.homeworkkansas.org/>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803943/usd262net/okuntylyovx2hn260gmt/PTOMeetingMinutes1919docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/nurses-page> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.kidshealth.org': <GET http://www.kidshealth.org/parent/firstaid_safe/>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803972/usd262net/s8sipel9qrbd1kwqrklg/FebPTOMeetingMinutes1120docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/document-library> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803909/usd262net/zcygtqo4nk94alxapei2/PTOMeetingMinutes1719.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803957/usd262net/kpvyrmpdxbbwic1o9mkw/1-21-20PTOMeetingMinutes21201docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/administration> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803928/usd262net/aprcr3g9v0x76agcz81m/PTOMeetingMinutes2219docx.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://west.usd262.net/about/sraff-directory> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/staff-directory>
2023-11-30 15:00:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://west.usd262.net> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/resource-manager/view/446cdd83-e743-495f-b0f1-91318deef052>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803888/usd262net/sun8frlao9rk4gftotnp/PTOMeetingMinutes2719.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803867/usd262net/cev2livmjpacfgyq0qrc/4202021PTOMeetingminutes.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803137/usd262net/km3nodsbggl5taziszk3/MicrosoftWord-TotallyCoolElementarySchool_1.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803819/usd262net/k5xboy8whfnymanvvuyk/MeetingminutesFeb.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803121/usd262net/u5ctbelnubnhgz9gw6wa/WestElementaryCounselingBrochurefinal-2008_1.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673784917/usd262net/lzwphtnhcoqjp9thds6n/FactSheet-TitleI-ParentInvolvement.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803778/usd262net/rwb5tlbdaap8e1wjiizl/NovemberPTOMeetingMinutes.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.usd262.net/enrollment/student-health-information> from <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/3541>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673784914/usd262net/dkc6smzfpcylihjyl0mx/ESIBoardPolicies-19.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803487/usd262net/eyojl1bd1qdj3lp8bjki/RICE-RestIceCompresionElevation_1.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673784913/usd262net/mlrg9xwsotm3a6ccmazy/ESI-DocumentsforWebsite-19.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803799/usd262net/rczvldr6kah713hisfwx/JanuaryPTOMeetingMinutes.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/report-bullying-safety-concerns> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about/emergency-safety-interventions-bullying)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673784915/usd262net/u4efohzm82jnbzzsqxd3/FERPANotificationofRights.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.p3tips.com': <GET https://www.p3tips.com/tipform.aspx?ID=217>
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.crisistextline.org': <GET https://www.crisistextline.org/texting-in/>
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.kbi.ks.gov': <GET https://www.kbi.ks.gov/sar>
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'usd262.onlinesafetyhub.io': <GET https://usd262.onlinesafetyhub.io/>
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803764/usd262net/yswpmxj1ivn5dr4onfue/OctoberPTOmeeting.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803749/usd262net/cfcylzqvhzvvsacorltx/SeptemberPTOmeetingnotes.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.usd262.net/about/news> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/)
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://west.usd262.net/fs/pages/3508> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about/document-library)
2023-11-30 15:00:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.usd262.net/schools> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/)
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803706/usd262net/doln0ockhdm39lkfntxm/NovPTOmeetingminutes162021.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803735/usd262net/zltnhhnyt2jz1fi8k8gy/MarchPTOMeetingMinutes222022.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803693/usd262net/fel78cnko0opxf96lefx/OctPTOMeetingminutes192021.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803721/usd262net/idowphs1sgrl2xrnellg/JanPTOMeetingMinutes1820221.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803679/usd262net/e6jc2mep0odspayjzxmo/SeptPTOMeetingMinutes.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803649/usd262net/eultmjehz33n29yf5nqt/PTOMeetingMinutes2020221.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803664/usd262net/x6uh9b9s0lxpm3h8nmdx/AugustthPTOMinutes.pdf
IGNORING PDF https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1673803634/usd262net/izumknwsghgbzuouu4ui/PTOMeetingMinutes2320221.pdf
2023-11-30 15:00:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.usd262.net/enrollment/student-health-information> (referer: https://west.usd262.net/about/nurses-page)
2023-11-30 15:00:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-11-30 15:00:44 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 38365,
 'downloader/request_count': 65,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 65,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 248536,
 'downloader/response_count': 65,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 24,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 34,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 402,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 8.931808,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 23, 0, 44, 907376),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 795436,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 69,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'offsite/domains': 35,
 'offsite/filtered': 962,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 25,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 65,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 65,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 65,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 65,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 23, 0, 35, 975568)}
```

Comment: Excellent response.  Thank you.  I had also concluded this was best approach and got close but couldn’t make it work.  https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2303#issuecomment-1829896931.  This gives me guide for how.

Comment: This mostly fixed it. thank you.  Credited you my gh thread above. Still have one case where something gets around the middleware using DENY_EXTENSIONS in a regex.  Can't seem to find a way to trap that error so I can find why?   See:  https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2303#issuecomment-1843019366

Comment: @leeprevost  Thanks, can you post the starting point for the crawl  so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: @leeprevost your failed link was `.../filedownload.ashx?moduleinst.........%20List.png`. (2 extensions in url) I assume that your regex identified it as allowed `.ashx` and ignored next `.png` extension.

Comment: I’m getting inconsistent results and suspect I need to process the Location header using w3lib safe_url_string similar to how it’s processed in the original redirect middleware.  My regex is just using the default DENY_EXTENSIONS list  looking for it at end of url string (see gh link above). .  I think header could be bytes?   

location = safe_url_string(response.headers["Location"])
        if response.headers["Location"].startswith(b"//"):
            request_scheme = urlparse(request.url).scheme
            location = request_scheme + "://" + location.lstrip("/")

Comment: An example would be on this page:  https://schools.scsk12.org/domain/4061.  I can't tell which link it is as the error only mentions referrer.  
2023-12-11 08:00:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://schools.scsk12.org/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=41384&dataid=55634&FileName=Virtually%20Everything.pdf> (referer: https://schools.scsk12.org/domain/4061)
Traceback (most recent call last):
And .pdf clearly in the link.

Comment: So, I can't seem to find a way to trap that so I can inspect the location field.  I think the bytes/decoding thing may be hanging up my regex.   I see that the default redirect mw uses: location = w3lib.url.safe_url_string(response.headers["Location"])

Comment: Another theory for my problem could be that the inconsistency is due to javascript?  I'm not using splash.

Comment: OK, the w3lib.url.safe_url_string(response.headers.get("Location", b"")) seems to work now.

Comment: Dang, I just had another one!  2023-12-11 10:44:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.argyleisd.com/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=689&dataid=1500&FileName=AWE%202023-2024%20SCHOOL%20SUPPLY%20LISTS.pdf> (referer: https://www.argyleisd.com/domain/46)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lee\PycharmProjects\

Not sure how mine is missing these?

Comment: And another:   ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.argyleisd.com/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=88&dataid=1421&FileName=2020-2021%20Adopted%20Budget.pdf> (referer: https://www.argyleisd.com/Page/74)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @leeprevost Have you tried adjusting your accept headers in your requests?

Comment: @Alexander:  Right now, running this plus a  User-Agent.  default_request_headers = {
    # 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    "Accept": "text/html",
    "Accept-Language": 'en-US',
    "Referrer": "http://www.google.com",

Comment: @leeprevost  I think it would be best to open a new question with the specifics of your current issue.